# Sum of product each row by a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `A` and a three-dims matrix `B`. I want to sum (by `i`)

`A(i,:)*B(i,:,:)`,

but without loops by `i`.

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you need, but how about: `M=bsxfun(@times,A(i,:),B(i,:,:)); sum(M(:))` Perhaps you can show how you do it with a loop, then we can see how to vectorize it.

Comment: Be helpful to give the dimensions of your matrix exactly, then we could post a more precise answer. Using bsxfun is probably going to be your best bet like Dennis used

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, but I don't want to use loops (by `i` in your version)

Comment: @АлександрКуракин You may want to avoid them in the final result. But if you don't show us exactly what you want to happen we need to guess what you are trying to achieve. Hopefully Amro managed to do this in his answer.

Comment: true, I posted a solution to the problem the way I understood it. If that doesnt match, then you need to explain further.. Either way I'm casting a vote to put on hold, until you make it clear you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start by creating some random matrices similar to what you described:

```
n = 4; m =3;
A = rand(n,m);
B = rand(n,m,5);
```

#### 1) loop version:

```
C = zeros(1,size(B,3));
for i=1:n
    C = C + A(i,:)*squeeze(B(i,:,:));
end
```

basically it performs matrix multiplication of each row of `A` by the corresponding slice of `B`, and accumulates the sum.

This is could be slighty improved by permuting the matrix `B` once outside the loop, thus avoiding the multiple calls to `squeeze`...

#### 2) vectorized version:

```
C = sum(sum(bsxfun(@times, permute(A,[2 3 1]),  permute(B, [2 3 1])),1),3);
```

I don't make any claims that this should be faster. In fact I suspect the looped version to be both faster and less memory intensive.

I'll leave it to you to compare the two using the actual dimensions are working with.

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I want!!! Thanks!!!
P.S. I could not use `bsxfun` properly because I didn't use `permute` properly.

Comment: @АлександрКуракин: I'm glad you solved your problem, but I'm not sure what you mean by that, `bsxfun` should work.. So my remark still stands, you should edit your question and add more details. Posts on this site should be clear enough to be helpful to other readers as well as the original person who asked the question.

Comment: and if `A` size is equal to `B` size? sum by `i`: `A(i,:,:)*B(i,:,:)`? Thanks very much!

Comment: your question is not very well formulated. For starters `size(A(i,:,:))` will be `[1 n m]`, but matrix multiplication in MATLAB is only defined for 2D matrices. Assuming you meant to use `squeeze` first, then you still have to make sure that the sizes are compatible with `size(A,3)` equal to `size(B,2)`.. So again I ask you to edit your question and be more specific, adding additional details to highlight exactly what you need

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution, a bit shorter:

```
C = A(:).'*reshape(B,[],size(B,3));
```

To be more readable you can use an equivalent solution like

```
C = arrayfun(@(x) sum(sum(A.*B(:,:,x))), 1:size(B,3));
```

But most probably the first solution will perform better.

Comment: Thanks! The second version is loop-equivalient in my homework... But the first is good!

Answer (score 1):

I see that the comment was not exactly what I had in mind. Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
M=bsxfun(@times,A,B); 
sum(M(:))
```