# Multiply matrices layer by layer

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, vectorization, bsxfun

I want to do this without loops:

```
% A ~ 4x2x3; B ~ 4x3x2; C ~ 4x2x2;
for i=1:4
  C(i,:,:) =  squeeze(A(i,:,:))*squeeze(B(i,:,:));
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support

Comment: @Dan thanks! But I need a simple code...

Comment: Shouldn't this be `C(i, :, :) = squeeze(A(i, :, :)) * squeeze(B(i, :, :))` or something?

Comment: probably you mean `C(i,:,:) = A(i,:,:)*B(i,:,:);` not `C(i,:,:) = A*B;`

Comment: Is this the same (homework) question as the one you asked earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441163/sum-of-product-each-row-by-a-matrix In that case please don't create a new one next time you find your initial question is unclear, just edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin No, `A` is a vector there. Solution won't work here.

Comment: I tried it with `A=rand(4,2,3); B = rand(4,3,2); C = zeros(4,2,2);` and your for loop gives an error. Please make sure the code is correct before you ask us to enhance it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't benchmarked this (so this is not guaranteed to be faster), but here goes:

```
[L, ma, na] = size(A);
[L, mb, nb] = size(B);
AX = reshape(permute(A, [2 1 3]), [], na);
BX = reshape(permute(B, [2 3 1]), mb, []);
CX = reshape(permute(reshape(AX * BX, ma, L, nb, L), [1 3 2 4]), ma, nb, []);
C = permute(CX(:, :, 1:L + 1:end), [3 1 2]);
```

Note that you might also run into memory problems if `A` and `B` are large (in which case you'll have to resort to loops).